# Space created below proof using proof.sty

Tags: logic, proof-package

I'm trying to typeset semantic readings of Gentzen sequent proofs like those shown [here](http://tinyurl.com/kgjqrtd).

I use the package proof.sty to produce the proofs.  However, if I want to put any kind of brackets around a proof, the root of the proof tree is treated as the middle of the block (I'm guessing) and so the brackets extend as far below the root as the proof extends above it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{proof}

\begin{document}

\[
\left\vert
\infer[\backslash_L]{N,N\backslash S\vdash S}{%
N\vdash N & S\vdash S}
\right\vert_{(x,y)}
\]

\end{document}
```

Is there any way out of this?  I have written quite a few proofs that I'd rather not have to re-code in some other package.

Comment: Can't view anything at the link you provided. Google books won't permit me to view that page. [Note that some books are viewable in some places but not others.]

Comment: But you certainly should see http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/.

Comment: That is, I know you say you don't want to use a package. But you will get better results more easily....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the baseline in several ways, the simplest is probably to use a `tabular` which centres by default:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{proof}

\begin{document}

\[
\left\vert
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\infer[\backslash_L]{N,N\backslash S\vdash S}{%
N\vdash N & S\vdash S}\end{tabular}
\right\vert_{(x,y)}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Moving the baseline seems to be the only way to go. I'm using an adjustbox now but the tabular suggestion is just as good AFAICT.